# Build an HTML table using XSLT 1.0

Tags: html, xml, xslt-1.0

I am building HTML Email for a campaign using XML and XSLT. I nearly have exactly what I want but I'm getting some repeated content and I can't figure out how to eliminate the duplicate elements.

There's one additional requirement I forgot to add originally: I need to add custom templates for each content element to apply different formatting based on the element. Also, there are random images in the content that need to be modeled

Here is some sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<job>
<surface>
<preheader><preheader_p>Click for more information</preheader_p></preheader>
<preheader><preheader_p>Questions? Call 877-555-1212</preheader_p></preheader>
<preheader><preheader_p>Click to unsubscribe</preheader_p></preheader>
<brand href="Images/logo.jpeg" />
<headline>Headline goes here</headline>
<subhead>Subhead goes here</subhead>
<body_copy>First paragraph goes here</body_copy>
<body_copy>Second paragraph goes here</body_copy>
<chart href="Images/graph.jpeg" />
<body_copy>Third paragraph goes here</body_copy>
</surface>
</job>
```

Using the XSLT I need to build a table that inserts the preheader content in the left column of a two-column nested table. In the right column I need to insert the product logo.

Once the preheader and logo content is displayed, the remaining content is inserted in sequence, each in their own table row.

Here is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<body>
<table width="600" border="1">
<tr><td>
<table width="100%" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td width="60%">
        <table width="100%" border="1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="job/surface/preheader" />          
        </table>
    </td>
    <td width="40%"><xsl:apply-templates select="job/surface/brand"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</td></tr>
<xsl:apply-templates select="job/surface" /> 
</table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="preheader"><tr><td style="font-size:11pt;"><xsl:value-of select="."/></td></tr>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="brand"><img style="max-width:100%" src="{@href}" />
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="headline"><tr><td style="font-size:20pt;"><xsl:value-of select="."/></td></tr>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="subhead"><tr><td style="font-size:16pt;"><xsl:value-of select="."/></td></tr>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="body_copy"><tr><td style="font-size:12pt;"><xsl:value-of select="."/></td></tr>
```

```
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is that the preheader and logo elements are repeating twice.

The goal is to create the following HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<table width="600" border="1">
<tr><td>
<table width="100%" border="1">
<tr><td width="60%"><table width="100%" border="1">
    <tr><td>Click for more information</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Questions? Call 877-555-1212</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Click to unsubscribe</td></tr>
    </table></td>
    <td width="40%"><img style="max-width:100%" src="Images/logo.jpeg"></td</tr>
</table></td></tr>
<tr><td style="font-size:20pt;">Headline goes here</td></tr>
<tr><td style="font-size:16pt;">Subhead goes here</td></tr>
<tr><td style="font-size:12pt;">First paragraph goes here</td></tr>
<tr><td style="font-size:12pt;">Second paragraph goes here</td></tr>
<tr><td><img style="max-width:100%" src="Images/graph.jpeg" /></td></tr>
<tr><td style="font-size:12pt;">Third paragraph goes here</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution that works perfectly. It combines Michael's fix of the repeated elements and provides for the application of templates to format the individual content elements. Thanks

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/job/surface">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
 </head>

 <body>
 <table width="600" border="0" align="center" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
 <tr><td><table width="100%"><tr><td width="60%" valign="bottom">
 <table width="100%"><tr><td style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px; font-size:10px;"><xsl:value-of select="preheader[1]"/></td></tr>
 <xsl:for-each select="preheader[position() > 1]">
 <tr><td style="padding: 0px 0px 5px 0px; font-size:10px;"><xsl:value-of select="."/></td></tr></xsl:for-each>
 </table></td>
 <td width="40%"><xsl:apply-templates select="brand"/></td></tr></table></td></tr>


 <xsl:apply-templates select="headline | subhead | bullet_level_1 | bullet_level_2 | body_copy | footnote | chart | logo | generic_image"/>            


 </table>
 </body>
 </html>

 </xsl:template>

<!--Add templates below to style each element...-->
<xsl:template match="headline"><tr><td class="headline full" valign="top" style=" font-size:150%; font-weight:bold;  color:#444444; padding-bottom:5px; padding-top:14px;"><xsl:apply-templates /></td></tr></xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="subhead"><tr><td class="subhead" style="padding: 5px 0px 0px 0px; color: rgb(181,26,138); font-size: 115%;"><xsl:apply-templates /></td></tr></xsl:template>
...
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that the preheader and logo elements are repeating
>   twice.

The reason why you have these duplicate rows is this instruction:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="job/surface" />
```

This effectively applies templates to **all** descendants of `surface`- including the `preheader` and `brand` nodes you have already handled.

One way to avoid this is to apply the templates selectively only to the nodes you need at this point:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="job/surface/headline | job/surface/subhead | job/surface/body_copy" />
```

---

BTW, I wonder if you could not make this simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/job">
    <html>
        <body>
            <table border="1">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="surface/preheader[1]"/>
                    </td>
                    <td rowspan="{count(surface/preheader)}">
                        <img style="max-width:100%" src="{@href}" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="surface/preheader[position() > 1]">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:for-each select="surface/headline | surface/subhead | surface/body_copy">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </table>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note also that your namespace declaration is not inherited by elements you create in other templates. You can see that a number of your table rows are in no-namespace :

```
<tr xmlns="">
```

You should move the default namespace declaration up to the `stylesheet` element, as shown in my example above.

Comment: I can't use the colspan or rowspan attributes. Because of the nature of the email clients we have to use nested tables as in my original example. I tried to revise your solution to generate a two-column table with nested elements, but I can't get it to generate the nesting properly.

Comment: I am afraid you have lost me at this point. If you cannot use  colspan/rowspan, then ignore my rewrite suggestion. Does not changing the `xsl:apply-templates` `select` expression solve the problem of duplicate rows?

Comment: Yes, duplicate rows is no longer a problem. But I realized that I need to apply custom templates for each element because we need to apply styling to the different elements. If you see the answer below, I modified your code to build the proper type of nesting tables.

Comment: "*I need to apply custom templates for each element*" Then it might be better to stick to your original strategy of `xsl:apply-templates`, rather than using `xsl:for-each`. Anyway, this seems to be a topic for another question.

Comment: OK. I will revise the question.

Comment: I don't think you should do that at this point. And I don't see why you - or anyone else - would downvote this answer. Did it not solve your problem?